# Tikz matrices/tikzcd: Add automatically a node at existing cells to point to it

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I am using `execute at begin cell` to automatically add some nodes in a tikzcd matrix (which is basically a tikz matrix, note that in practice I actually use it only on a subset of nodes, for for simplicity here I enable it for all cells), and I use:

```
name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn
```

in order to make sure that this node should be the destination of arrows like `\arrow[r]` in tikzcd. When the node is empty or contains something like `\node{foo};`, I can easily do that, but the problem is that when the node contains `\rar`, then tikz [automatically adds](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/6e5fd71581ab04351a89553a259b57988bc28140/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex#L40C7-L40C7) a dummy empty node that contains only `name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn`, which will overwrite my own `name` definition: as a result, the link points to the coordinate (0,0) instead of pointing to my node (see the second node):

[image]

I tried to use instead `execute at end cell`, but unfortunately it does not work as I get an error `\node` not defined. Any idea what I’m doing wrong?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}


This gives the good result, except for the second element: I’d like the arrows to point to the node and not to the coordinate:

\begin{tikzcd}[cells={inner sep=0pt},/tikz/execute at begin cell={\node[rounded corners, fill=orange,inner sep=3pt, opacity=.5,name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn]{OOOO};}]
  \node{A}; \rar["bad\ \ "] &  \rar & \node{A}; \rar & \text{I don't have strong preferences on what should happen here}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, the magic thingy that tries to figure out if the cell is just the node contents (with possible `|<options>|`) doesn't see a path (i.e. a `\path`, `\draw`, `\node`, …) so it assumes it to be just a node in its implicit form. (You can do `Foo \rar Bar`, the `\arrow` will normally executed inside the node text box.) I have two solutions: 1. `& \path; \rar &` 2. disabling the magic thingy either by doing `/tikz/matrix of nodes/.code=` (a bit radical because it resets some other settings we might want to keep) or by carefully undefining these magic macros provided by the `matrix` library.

Comment: The “radical” solution works very well with TikZ-CD because it uses `\matrix` internally (so the `matrix` key is not necessary) and it uses its `asymmetrical rectangle` node shape which makes the `anchor=base` setting of `matrix of nodes` almost irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel. Option 1 is not possible (too heavy and break existing code), option 2.1 is indeed a bit too radical. So option 2.2 is like patchcmd? Also, I’m curious: why can't I make `execute at end` work? It would overwrite the name given by the matrix this way… but I can't make it work.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel But wouldn't the radical solution completely disable the short syntax `|[foo]| bar`? I sometimes want to use it for cells where I don't add a node first (in the MWE I set it true for all cells, but in practice I selectively run these code only on some cells).

Comment: Yes it would disable the short syntax. For these `execute at end/begin <thing>` keys the order matters (they're basically a `\appto` to some internal macros). In your current code a cell becomes `\node{OOOO}; \magicDetector <cell content> \magicDetectorEnd`. With `execute at end cell` it becomes: `\magicDetector <cell content> \node{OOOO}; \magicDetectorEnd` (the end macro does `\egroup;` to end the node operation if the short syntax was detected). You need to do `every matrix/.append style={execute at end cell={\node[name=…]{OOOO};}}` so that this get added after the end macro.

Comment: You will still have that empty node then, of course, unless you disable the magic detection for that cell. You've wrote that you might need your OOOO nodes only in select cells. It should be possible to disable the magic detection thing for a specific cell. (Similar to 2.2 but with keys `row <r> column <c>`.) And not necessarly `\patchcmd` just letting the internal macros to `\relax` or `\empty`.

Comment: Ok, so it seems like if I do `every matrix/.append style={execute at end cell={\node[rounded corners,fill=red]{A};}}` it solves the problem… but it breaks other parts of my code, no idea why… I need to investigate to see if it is just a stupid mistake or something inherently bad from this solution. @Qrrbrbirlbel the problem with letting internal macros to `\relax` is that I’m affraid to break other parts of the code that might rely on them… but it might be the case that it is the only part that need it, not sure I need to test, but thanks for the idea.